# How save and get data in SQLite from two differen activity?

Tags: android, sqlite, get, save

When my app is started, I get tiket from server that I use for sign response to server. This ticket (string) I save in database and when I run new response I get this tiket from database and attach to response. All was fine when I run responses from same activity where I save my ticket. I mean that when I am saving tiket, I also releases context of activity where I am executing this actions with database. BUT when I save tiket in one activity, launch another activity and try to get ticket from database in second activity, I get null (rown didn't contain item). So, can anybody tell me, where I'm erred?

I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Here code:

```
    public long setTicket(Ticket ticket) throws SQLException {
    ContentValues insertValues = new ContentValues();
    insertValues.put(TicketTable.KEY_TICKET, ticket.getTicket());
    insertValues.put(TicketTable.KEY_RESULT_CODE, ticket.getResultCode());

    long result = m_db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_TICKET, null, insertValues);

    return result;
}

public Ticket getTicket() throws SQLException {
    String[] columns = { TicketTable.KEY_ID, TicketTable.KEY_TICKET,
            TicketTable.KEY_RESULT_CODE };
    Cursor cursor = getCursor(DATABASE_TABLE_TICKET, columns);

    Ticket result = new Ticket();
    result.setTicket(cursor.getString(TicketTable.TICKET_COLUMN));
    result.setResultCode(cursor.getString(TicketTable.RESULT_CODE_COLUMN));

    cursor.close();

    return result;
}
```

Here methods where I set access to database:

```
    public String getTicket(){
    DBAdapter adapter = new DBAdapter(m_context);
    adapter.open();
    String ticketEncoded = null;
    Ticket ticket = null;
    try {
        ticket = adapter.getTicket();
        ticketEncoded = java.net.URLEncoder.encode(ticket.getTicket());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        adapter.close();
    }

    return ticketEncoded;
}

public void saveTicketFromServer(){
    GetTicketHandler handler = new GetTicketHandler(m_context);
    Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
    ticket.setCommand("getTicket");

    TicketTask task = new TicketTask(ticket);
    createTask(task, handler);
}
```

And here I have caught null insted of ticket:

```
        String comment = java.net.URLEncoder.encode(strToEncode, "UTF-8");
    String barcodeId = "4605246006340";
    String ball = "10";
    String sign = account.getTicket();//here!
    CreateCommentTask task = new CreateCommentTask(barcodeId, ball,
            comment, sign);
    //TODO create handler
    HttpService httpService = new HttpService();
    httpService.createTask(task, null);
```

But in another response all fine:

```
String sign = account.getTicket();
    try {
        task = new SearchBarcodeTask(searchForm, sign);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    SearchBarcodeHandler handler = new SearchBarcodeHandler(m_activity);

    HttpService httpService = new HttpService();
    httpService.createTask(task, handler);
```

Comment: Post your code and error logs.

Answer (score 0):

Alright the problem that I see is that `String sign = account.getTicket();//here!`

The account has to be null. So check what you are doing differently between the two other method calls you mentioned. You are doing something different with whatever account is.

Comment: No-no, instance of account not null. Problem when I try to get ticket. Before I put ticket in table and when I get it for another response all ok. But when I try to get ticket for this response, the table where should be tiket didn't contain any rows.

Comment: Post your stack trace so I can see for myself what the error is please.